# Having trouble figuring out how to create many-to-many relationship between a table and itself in Sequelize.js ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My goal is to create friendship functionality between users. For this, I am thinking of creating 2 tables so far:

```
Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password, email
```

And

```
Table: Friendships
Columns: id, userId1, userId2, accepted
```

I'm thinking about creating a many-to-many relationship between the user table and itself through the junction table friendship. The friendship table will contain the userId of both users and a boolean accepted that symbolizes whether the friendship is accepted or pending. The friendship is always 2 sided, if user A is friends with user B, that means user B is also friends with user A

The problem is that the many-to-many relationship between the table Users and itself boggles my mind a bit. In Sequelize.js, when I'm making a many-to-many relationship, I do it like this:

```
User.belongsToMany(Server, { through: ServerUser })
Server.belongsToMany(User, { through: ServerUser })
```

I state the user can belong to many server, and that the server can belong to many users. This relationship is linked through the ServerUser table.

Now considering I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between the user table and itself, If I follow the same route, I'd have to do something like this:

```
User.belongsToMany(User, { through: Friendship })
User.belongsToMany(User, { through: Friendship })
```

Which makes no sense to me. What approach can I try?

Answer (score 0):

#### I took the liberty to define the tables myself using the info you provided:

> ```
> Table: Users
> Columns: id, username, password, email
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```
> Table: Friendships
> Columns: id, userId1, userId2, accepted
> ```

#### I think the following code will solve your problem:

```js
const User = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
  }
);

const Friendship = sequelize.define(
  'Friendship',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    accepted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
  }
);

Friendship.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId1',
  unique: false
});

Friendship.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId2',
  unique: false
});
```

#### These definitions will generate the following in `postgreSQL` (Showing just the `Friendship` table):

```sql
CREATE TABLE public."Friendship"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Friendship_id_seq"'::regclass),
    accepted boolean NOT NULL,
    "userId1" integer,
    "userId2" integer,
    CONSTRAINT "Friendship_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "Friendship_userId1_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userId1")
        REFERENCES public."User" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Friendship_userId2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userId2")
        REFERENCES public."User" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```